# Python : Checking number of occurrences of ngrams, per line, in a text file

Tags: python

So i have a file with a list of ngrams, delimited by newline char. It looks like this:

```
got to love
makes perfect sense
going to be
would have guessed
can not wait
more important than
```

I also have a text file with lines of sentences, also delimited by newline char. Lets say it looks like this:

```
I got to love you.
Hello world
Well boy
That makes perfect sense. I can not wait.
Hello
```

I want to be able to iterate through each line and count how many times, as a whole, any of those ngrams occur. So my output for the above would be:

```
1
0
0
2
0
```

How would i achieve this?

Comment: I had tried this but its returning all zeros

`def checkLine(line):
    count = 0
    with open("tr_response_trigrams_list.txt") as f:
        for ngram in f:
            if ngram in line:
                count += 1
    print count

for line in open("/Users/user/Code/abstract/data/Training(3500)/3500_Response_Tweets.txt", "r"):
    checkLine(line)  `

Comment: I dont know how your program should work why is there a  2 in line 4?

Comment: Because it contains both 'makes perfect sense' and 'can not wait'

Comment: it is always good to have your code in your question. its readable and others can help you better

Answer (score 0):

I leave the rest to you

```
for sentence in sentences:
    count = 0
    for ngram in ngrams:
        if ngram in sentence:
            count += 1
    print count
```